# Error: Target of repeat operator is not specified

Tags: regex, bash, expression

Unable to run regular expression using grep -E. Regex works as intended with PERL & JavaScript, but need it to work within a bash script.

Tried using non-capture groups to ensure "+" operator only references the character or character class.

```
(?:POWERPNT\.EXE\s+Error\s[0-9]+\s)([\s\S]+?)(?=[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z$)
```

I need the bash script to return a match.

Comment: Define "return a match".

Comment: `(?:` is a perlism, and is not valid ERE syntax; either remove it, or use `grep -P` (if your version supports it).

Comment: Please prove it works in JS with a demo. The pattern looks rather combersome.

Comment: Looking closer, I see more perlisms: Using `\s` and `\S` inside `[ ]` (as opposed to using them as independent items), and `+?`, and `(?=`. Basically, you're using the wrong variant of RE syntax for the situation.